# How to place more elements with socket.io when client joins?

Tags: jquery, socket.io

I am willing to create a new `div` element, right next to the first one, when the second client joins/connects the server:

app.js

```
...
io.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log("Client connected...");
    client.emit('add_player');
});
...
```

index.ejs

```
...
server.on('add_player', function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.field').append(player);
            });
        });
    });
...
```

I get only one element on each browser. This is what I get:

[image: Quiz]

And this is what I would like to achieve. But how?

[image: Quiz][image: Quiz]

Comment: I assume I have to pass those divs to other clients.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think its because you are emitting the function only on the client which currently gets connected to the server. Then when you are getting a new connection you are again emitting the function only one the present client and not bothered about the old connections, neither you are looking how many previous connections have been done and emitting that many times the function on the present client. Instead you are just emitting only once.

So what you require is that you have to maintain an array of clients and push the new client into the array on every connection.

```
var clientArray = new Array();
```

and on connection listener you need the following modification

```
io.on('connection', function(client){
console.log("Client connected...");
for(i=0;i<clientArray.length;i++)
    clientArray[i].emit('add_player');     //emitting the function once to all ohter clients because a new client has been added

clientArray.push(client);                  // pushing the new client to the array
for(i=0;i<clientArray.length;i++)
    client.emit('add_player');            // emitting the function on the new client exactly equal to the number of client presently in the array
});
```

Comment: it aint it. there must be something wrong with the append function, 'cause even if I try to add two div elements at a time, it only adds one.

Comment: yup! i think there is something wrong in your append function. Have you verified that the position of the newly created div element is aside to the previous one and the divs are not overlapping.. show your append code people over here might help you out...

Comment: it's just it: `<body>
 <div class="field">
 </div>
 <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
 <script>
  var server = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  
  server.on('add_player', function () {
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.field').append(player);
    $('.field').append(player);
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>`

Comment: @TomaszSzymanek buddy you got me wrong. I asked you what you append(player) method actually do, instead you gave me how you are calling that particular function. No problem! you just add the body of append function and if it is too big then edit your question and add there (It's difficult to read the code here in comments)

Comment: `var player = $( '<div class="well gracz_pojemnik">' +
    '<span id="kto"><h1>Ty</h1></span><span class="label" id="licznik">30</span>' + //kto + czas
    '</br><hr>' +
    '</div>');`

I can't even pass two of those:
`$('.field').append(player);
$('.field').append(player);`

Comment: @TomaszSzymanek what is the value of the property position of class well gracz_pojemnik in your css file? Secondly I suggest you to avoid the static id property in your code which you are going to repeat, because it creates many elements with the same id and breaks the rule that the 'id' should be unique.( If it is necessary then please generate a unique id each time. )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32004/discussion-between-sumitb-mdi-and-tomasz-szymanek)